# Reading ID value always is 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a database from which I want to read a particular value.

When I am reading `ID` is always showing up as 0.

```
public void ClustersStatus(Clusters cl)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-JMGPJ6J;Initial Catalog=Infinity;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Approved from Master_Cluster where ClusterID = @id", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cl.ClusterID);

            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();

                if (Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Approved"]) == 1)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }

        // return cl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which ID you are talking about? There is one that you gave as a parameterin your sql command, is that it? Also it would be better to put your connection string to some settings file instead of writing it hard-coded in your code.

Comment: Always use SQL Server Management Studio to test your query before using it in c#.  Either the query is wrong, or id parameter type is different in c# and SQL Server, or you are searching in the wrong database/data table.

Comment: cl.ClusterID , I am taking from Class

Comment: Select Approved from Master_Cluster Where ClusterID = 5  I it will show the result but when coming in to C# Cluster.ID =0

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to answer your question without even more information about your specific problem, but I think the real issue in your

```
rdr.Read();
```

line. [`SqlDataReader.Read` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8) advances your data reader to the *next* record which means that you are reading your `rdr["Approved"]` column of your **next** line  with your

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Approved"]) == 1)
```

code which seems weird and I think this is not what you want. You might wanna consider to delete it.

Also I have a few suggestions;

- Do *not* put your connection string directly in your code. These settings can be change over time to time. Put it some configuration file or read it from some settings file.
- Open your connection  object just before you use it. Not a big deal, but it is a good practice.
- Do *not* use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method instead (preferably [`Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_))

Comment: Issue is Cluster.ID I am passing Class Properties in to here

Comment: @Easwaran You probably won't assing  your `ID` property than which has 0 for default value. Did you debug your code and see your `Cluster.ID` is _really_ have 5? Do you have a code something like `Cluster cl = new Cluster(); cl.ID = 5;` that passed to your `ClustersStatus` method?

Comment: I am hardcoded that five for example cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 5);

Comment: @Easwaran Again, as I said, you are reading the next line in your data reader. That's seems weird if your sql query returns one record. Have you ever try to delete that `rdr.Read();` line? Do you even need it? It is really hard to solve your problem as such since we _can't_ know how deep the rabbit hole.

Comment: Cluster cl = new Cluster(); cl.ID = 5; Even I delete it to rdr.read same result 0 idont know why it coming my query is correct is it?

Answer (score 0):

Supposed your query offers you what you want, to be able to use the data read with `SqlDataReader`, you need to use the `IDataRecord` interface. You cannot use directly the `rdr` variable.

For ease of use, the I wrote the reading engine into a function. I am writing here the idea for you to adapt it to your needs:

```
        private static int ReadSingleRow(IDataRecord record)
        {
//below is an example of processing using `record`. You adapt it to your needs
            int.TryParse(record[0].ToString(), out int temp);
            MessageBox.Show (temp.ToString());
//...do the processing you need
            return temp;
        }
```

After you wrote the function, the main becomes:

```
              if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                  while (rdr.Read());
                   int x=ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord) rdr); 
//or use, somehow, the above function
// other processing

                }
```